# How can I connect to a MS SQL instance?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to browse the .DAT files or connect to a MS SQL Server instance?

Answer (score 5):

[SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en)?

There are also third-party browsers for MSDE 2000, such as [MSDE Admin](http://www.msde.biz/msdeadmin/msdeadmin.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I think the SQL Server Management Studio Express is what you're looking for

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en